# Spring Data Rest Projection to get value from different entity

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have two entities. One is the parent (for which I have a projection) and the other entity has FK relation with the parent. My parent entity does "not" have bidirectional relationship (mappedBy).

How do I expose/get the child entity in the projection I have for the parent.

Here is how I want.
Parent:

```
public class EntityA implements java.io.Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ENTITYAID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer entityAID;
......
}
```

Child:

```
public class EntityB {

@EmbeddedId
private EntityBPk entityBPk;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ENTITYAID", referencedColumnName = "ENTITYAID",insertable=false,updatable=false)
private EntityA entityA;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ENTITYCID", referencedColumnName = "ENTITYCID",insertable=false,updatable=false)
private EntityC entityC;

@Column(name = "DUMMY")
private String dummy;

}
```

I want to access EntityB from EntityA's projection. Something like below.

Projection for EntityA:

```
@Projection(name = "projEntityA", types = { EntityA.class }) 
public interface EntityAProjection {
.....
Set<EntityB> getEntityBs();

}
```

**Note:
But I don't have any reference of EntityB inside EntityA (since I don't want bidirectional relationship)**

This may not be needed. But just FYI.

```
public class EntityBPk implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "ENTITYAID", nullable = false)
private Integer entityAID;

@Column(name = "ENTITYCID", nullable = false)
private Integer entityCId;

}
```

Thanks
Bharath

Comment: If I understand well, you would need to iterate somehow through the child objects and read the FK, I suggest you use the word 'owner' instead of 'parent' to avoid confusion

Comment: If the owner does not know its children you won't be successful with projections. I think the `owner` should also own the relationship. So I think I would turn the relationship around (I try to avoid bidirectional relations).